# What is the differens between <class> tmp = <value>; and <class> tmp; tmp = <value>;?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class with overloaded *operator=(const char&)*

```
_obj operator=(const char& in){
    this->out = convert(in);
    return *this;
}
```

with '*this->out*' being of class *`string`*

I can do:

```
_obj tmp;
tmp = 'c';
```

and program compiles and run as intended.

But when I do:

```
_obj tmp = 'c';
```

I get a compile error:

> error: conversion from 'char' to non-scalar type '_obj' requested.

What exactly is the differens between these two statements?

First statement creates an object of type _obj with constructor *_obj::_obj()*  with first line and use the overloaded *operator=(const char&)* to assign the *char* with the second line.

The second statement tries to directly convert a char to type of _obj, but why is that so, when there is a *operator=* telling what to do.

How would the class and operator would have to be formed to allow creation and assignment in a single line of code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `_obj tmp = 'c';` requires a constructor accepting a `char`.

Comment: I allready tried to give a constructor _obj::_obj(const char& in) but still got the compiler error

Comment: My bad. I missed the simple word const in the constructor. Now it works as expected. I wonder why the compiler tried to convert from char to _obj instead of telling me of illegal conversion from const char to char.